# Capybara + Steak + SSL

Tags: ssl, capybara

I'm using Steak + Capybara for acceptance testing and rack-ssl for SSL enforcement, now, when I tried to run the test suite, I've got the error message

(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Capybara launches plain app server (Mongrel/Webrick), which doesn't support SSL. To get SSL environment on your local machine you'd have to setup something like nginx or Apache with mod_ssl and mod_proxy to accept SSL connections and proxy plain HTTP requests to your devel server.

You can then launch it in your test environment setup, and in your tests to navigate to this SSL server rather than app server itself.

Caveats:

To set up "ssl server" you will have to create a self-signed SSL certificate. A browser does not trust it by default until you add it to the list of exceptions. AFAIR Capybara selenium driver creates a new Firefox profile each time, so it will reject your SSL cert. You might have to purchase a "real" certificate.

Capybara launches its internal server on random available port, you will need to change it. I recall writing something along the lines of:

```
Capybara::Server.class_eval do
  def find_available_port
     @port = 3000
  end
end
```